# Compare-Object in Powershell for 2 objects based on a field within. Objects populated by JSON and XML

Tags: json, powershell, compareobject, incapsula

Apologies for my lack of powershell knowledge, have been searching far and wide for a solution as i am not much of a programmer.

Background:

I am currently trying to standardise some site settings in Incapsula. To do this i want to maintain a local XML with rules and use some powershell to pull down the existing rules and compare them with what is there to ensure im not doubling up. I am taking this approach of trying to only apply the deltas as:

1. For most settings incapsula is not smart enough to know it already exists
2. What can be posted to the API is different varies from what is returned by the API

Examples:

Below is an example of what the API will return on request, this is in a JSON format.

```
JSON FROM WEBSITE

{
"security": {
        "waf": {
            "rules": [{
                "id": "api.threats.sql_injection",
                "exceptions": [{
                    "values": [{
                        "urls": [{
                            "value": "google.com/thisurl",
                            "pattern": "EQUALS"
                        }],
                        "id": "api.rule_exception_type.url",
                        "name": "URL"
                    }],
                    "id": 256354634
                }]
            }, {
                "id": "api.threats.cross_site_scripting",
                "action": "api.threats.action.block_request",
                "exceptions": [{
                    "values": [{
                        "urls": [{
                            "value": "google.com/anotherurl",
                            "pattern": "EQUALS"
                        }],
                        "id": "api.rule_exception_type.url",
                        "name": "URL"
                    }],
                    "id": 78908790780
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the format of the XML with our specific site settings in it

```
OUR XML RULES
    <waf>
    <ruleset>
        <rule>
            <id>api.threats.sql_injection</id>
                <exceptions>
                    <exception>
                        <type>api.rule_exception_type.url</type>
                        <url>google.com/thisurl</url>   
                    </exception>
                    <exception>
                        <type>api.rule_exception_type.url</type>
                        <url>google.com/thisanotherurl</url>
                    </exception>
                </exceptions>
        </rule>
        <rule> 
            <id>api.threats.cross_site_scripting</id>
                <exceptions>
                    <exception>
                        <type>api.rule_exception_type.url</type>
                        <url>google.com/anotherurl</url>
                    </exception>
                    <exception>
                        <type>api.rule_exception_type.url</type>
                        <url>google.com/anotherurl2</url>
                    </exception> 
                </exceptions>
        </rule> 
    </ruleset>
</waf>
```

I have successfully been able to compare other settings from the site against the XML using the compare-object command, however they had a bit simpler nesting and didn't give me as much trouble. I'm stuck to whether it is a logic problem or a limitation with compare object. An example code is below, it will require the supplied json and xml saved as stack.json/xml in the same directory and should produce the mentioned result :

```
    $existingWaf = Get-Content -Path stack.json | ConvertFrom-Json
    [xml]$xmlFile = Get-Content -Path stack.xml 

    foreach ($rule in $xmlFile)
    {
        $ruleSet = $rule.waf.ruleset
    }

    foreach ($siteRule in $ExistingWaf.security.waf.rules)
        {
            foreach ($xmlRule in $ruleSet)
            {
                if ($xmlRule.rule.id -eq $siteRule.id)
                    {
                        write-output "yes"
                        $delta = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject @($siteRule.exceptions.values.urls.value | Select-Object) -DifferenceObject @($xmlRule.rule.exceptions.exception.url | Select-Object) -IncludeEqual | where {$xmlRule.rule.id -eq $siteRule.id}
                        $delta

                    }
            }
        }
```

This is kind of working but not quite what i wanted. I do get a compare between the objects but not for the specific id's, it shows me the results below:

```
    InputObject                                 SideIndicator
    -----------                                 -------------
    google.com/thisurl                               ==
    google.com/thisanotherurl                        =>
    google.com/anotherurl                            =>
    google.com/anotherurl2                           =>

    google.com/anotherurl                            ==
    google.com/thisurl                               =>
    google.com/thisanotherurl                        =>
    google.com/anotherurl2                           =>
```

Where as i am more after

```
    InputObject                                 SideIndicator
    -----------                                 -------------
    google.com/thisurl                               ==
    google.com/thisanotherurl                        =>

    google.com/anotherurl                            ==
    google.com/anotherurl2                           =>
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Is it possible to only do the compares only on the values where the ids match?

Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem was your iteration logic**, which **mistakenly processed *multiple* rules from the XML document in a single iteration**:

- `foreach ($xmlRule in $ruleSet)` didn't enumerate anything - instead it processed the single `<ruleset>` element; to enumerate the child `<rule>` elements, you must use `$ruleSet.rule`.
- `$xmlRule.rule.exceptions.exception.url` then *implicitly* iterated over *all* `<rule>` children and therefore reported the URLs across *all* of them, which explains the extra lines in your `Compare-Object` output.

Here's a streamlined, annotated version of your code:

```
$existingWaf = Get-Content -LiteralPath stack.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$xmlFile = [xml] (Get-Content -raw -LiteralPath stack.xml )

# No need for a loop; $xmlFile is a single [System.Xml.XmlDocument] instance.
$ruleSet = $xmlFile.waf.ruleset

foreach ($siteRule in $ExistingWaf.security.waf.rules)
{
    # !! Note the addition of `.rule`, which ensures that the rules
    # !! are enumerated *one by one*. 
    foreach ($xmlRule in $ruleSet.rule)
    {
        if ($xmlRule.id -eq $siteRule.id)
        {
          # !! Note: `$xmlRule` is now a single, rule, therefore:
          # `$xmlRule.rule.[...]-> `$xmlRule.[...]`
          # Also note that neither @(...) nor Select-Object are needed, and
          # the `| where ...` (Where-Object) is not needed.
          Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $siteRule.exceptions.values.urls.value `
                         -DifferenceObject $xmlRule.exceptions.exception.url -IncludeEqual
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Additional observations regarding your code**:

- There is no need to ensure that operands passed to `Compare-Object` are *arrays*, so there's no need to wrap them in array sub-expression operator `@(...)`. `Compare-Object` handles scalar operands fine.
- `... | Select-Object` is a virtual *no-op* - the input object is passed *through*<sup>[1]</sup>
- `... | Where-Object {$xmlRule.rule.id -eq $siteRule.id}` is pointless, because it duplicates the enclosing `foreach` loop's condition.

  - Generally speaking, because you're not referencing the pipeline input object at hand via automatic variable `$_`, your `Where-Object` filter is *static* and will either match *all* input objects (as in your case) or *none*.

---

<sup>[1] There *is* a subtle, invisible side effect that *typically* won't make a difference: `Select-Object` adds an invisible `[psobject]` wrapper around the input object, which on rare occasions does cause different behavior later -
 see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer. Unfortunately i do not have enough reputation to vote for it but i have selected it as the correct answer.


My actual implementation is giving me the error

Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DifferenceObject' because it is null.



So i will have to investigate where the null is appearing from. This could be because the JSON in reality is not from a file but rather from a web request so i will try and implement a null check somewhere to get the compare working.




Thanks again.

Comment: No worries about the up-vote at all - accepting is enough to signal to future readers that an answer was effective. As for your error: I encourage you to step through your code in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: Using Visual Studio i was able to step through and see that 1 of the settings on the site had a parameter set but not a URL. I will now determine the best way to proceed with producing a delta. Thanks for the tip!